# Can the spell "Command" be used to cause unwitting damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The PHB gives the following description of the 1st-level spell Command (emphasis mine), and I'm curious about the implications of the RAW here:

> You speak a one-word command to a creature you can see within range. The target must succeed on a Wisdom saving throw or follow the command on its next turn. The spell has no effect if the target is undead, if it doesn’t understand your language, **or if your command is directly harmful to it**.

So my question is about the "directly harmful" clause.  From an "in-universe" perspective, it seems reasonable that a creature's self-preservation instincts would prevent it from knowingly injuring itself; but what if the harm is caused by something that the Commanded creature is unaware of?  For instance, if you poisoned one of their rations, could you command them to eat it?

Similarly, if neither the caster nor the Commanded creature are aware of the danger, would the command fail?  For instance, if you order a creature to walk towards you, but there's a pit hidden by an illusion between the two of you.

If this causes the spell to fail, could it be used as a foolproof trap detector (Command a party member to walk down a hallway, knowing that the spell would prevent them from harming themselves, and thus prevent them from moving if there is a trap ahead)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Can the spell "Command" be used to cause unwitting damage?

RAW: Yes, you can, **IF** that damage is unbeknownst to the target (and in most cases the caster as well).  You could not tell the target to walk off a cliff, jump into the spike pit, or smash its face into your Paladin's Warhammer.  You **could** however tell the target to walk down a hallway you *suspect* but are not *certain* may contain traps.  Why? Because it wouldn't be "directly harmful to it", it would be potentially indirectly harmful to it.  What if it doesn't trigger any of the traps you aren't even sure are (and may not even be) down there? So no, it could not be used as a foolproof trap detector because unless the GM tells you and you (your character) becomes aware there are traps in said hallway, the spell would not fail.  Let's say you poisoned one of their 5 rations and then told them to eat one?  You can't be sure which one the target will eat, so it's still indirect.

As for the in-universe thought process?  You are exactly correct.  Self preservation would cause the magical command to fail, to cease functioning, to not take effect.  If the target is unaware that it needs preserve its own life from something that *might* occur as a result of following the given command, then there would be no need for self preservation, and thus it would follow your command.

Comment: I think the trap example confuses matters; you suggest that it’s necessary for the *caster* to be unaware of the danger, but the spell seems to clearly indicate that it is the *target* that must be unaware.

Comment: Well, the only thing the spell indicates is that none of your commands can be directly harmful to it.  If the caster knew there were traps, and tried to walk the target into them, under rules as written it wouldn't succeed, because the caster would know that directly harms the target.  You bring up a good point that the target can't know there are traps in said hallway either, though, even if the caster did not.

Comment: If the target knows there *are* traps in the hallway, there's at least some chance he knows how to avoid them. (ie. A Kobold knows where the pit trap trigger is) In that case he would obey the command while avoiding triggering them because he knows how.

Comment: The idea of the spell seems to be that the compulsion isn't strong enough to make the target do something the target knows will hurt. Whether the *caster* knows it will hurt doesn't seem to be relevant.

Comment: @CrusaderJ Damn...that's tricky.  I hadn't thought of it that way.  Perhaps this spell is more complicated than I thought.

Comment: @ObliviousSage But the caster knowing it will hurt IS **directly** relevant to *'if your command is directly harmful to it'* , no? The spell description is not saying "if the *target* thinks your command is harmful to it." it simply informs the caster that if your command is directly harmful then it wont obey it.  I believe that implies knowledge on the caster's part.

Comment: @Airatome I think the key word here is _directly_ harmful, as in the command itself is "be harmed in this manner". Even a creature with the lowest Wisdom has enough instinct not to follow that. But a command that puts the target into a situation that will hurt afterwards...I would argue that's _indirect_ harm. Commanding a guy to move on top of a trap is like commanding him to move closer to his teammates so your fellow wizard can include him in his fireball. Both of those are harms which are triggered after the command has been completed. Only difference is the trap was already there.

Comment: @Airatome and before anyone says anything, I do believe that "walk off a cliff" is a command of direct harm, even though the harm is merely implied. Unless the creature feels that the action won't harm them, like if they can levitate or are just really really dumb. It's a wisdom saving throw, after all. Creatures with high enough wisdom to detect the self-harm intent in the caster's Command would probably save against the Command itself in the first place. If they don't, it would just mean they didn't detect it.